# How to merge and divide two strings with some step?

Tags: c#, algorithm, substring

**My task:** Merge and divide two strings with some step.

> For example:
>   
>  text = "abcd" 
>  key = "12" 
>  step = 2
>   
> **result** = "1ab2cd"

**Пример:**

 1) Merging strings.

> **Input variables:**
>   text = "abcd" 
>  key = "12" 
>  step = 2
>
> **Output variables:**
>   result = "1ab2cd"

2) Now I need to **decrypt the result of string to the source data**, where key. Length and step variables are known.

> **Input variables:**
>   result = "1ab2cd" 
>  key.Length = 2 
>  step = 2
>   
> **Output variables:**
>   text = "abcd" 
>  key = "12"

Algorithm (1) has already been implemented:

```
    int step, word;
    string text, key, result = string.Empty;

    Console.Write("Enter Text : ");
    text = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.Write("Enter Key : ");
    key = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.Write("Enter Step : ");
    step = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

    // MIX ARRAY
    word = 0;

    if (step <= text.Length)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < key.Length; i++)
        {
            result += key.Substring(i, 1);
            for (int k = 0; k < step; k++)
            {
                try
                {
                    result += text.Substring(word, 1);
                    word++;
                }
                catch
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        if (word < text.Length)
        {
            result += text.Substring(word, (text.Length - word));
        }
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Result Text : " + result);

    // DECIPHER ARRAY

    Console.WriteLine("text: " + text);
    Console.WriteLine("key: " + key);
    Console.ReadKey();
```

How to implement the algorithm (2)?

Comment: for what input doesn't it work? What is the result you get?..

Comment: @GiladGreen 
text = "abcde";
key = "123";
step = 1;
result = "1a2b3c"

Comment: If step = 2 then **Error: Index was outside the bounds of the array.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will write this as another code block you can merge 2 algorthym if you want.
Again Think with my 4 steps.

1- Find what variables do you need?

```
        string key = "", text = "", result;
        int step = 0, keyLength, textLength, word = 0;
```

2- Take All Values

```
        Console.Write("Result Text : ");
        result = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Write("Key Length: ");
        keyLength = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        textLength = result.Length - keyLength;
        Console.Write("Step: ");
        step = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
```

3- Think about algorthym

4- Think about that may arise exceptions

```
       for (int i = 0; i < result.Length; i = word)
        {
            if (keyLength > 0)
            {
                key += result.Substring(word, 1);
                word++;
                keyLength--;
            }
            if (textLength > 0)
            {
                for (int k = 0; k < step; k++)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        text += result.Substring(word, 1);
                        word++;
                        textLength--;
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

        }
        Console.WriteLine("Text : " + text);
        Console.Write("Key : " + key);
        Console.ReadKey();
```

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> text = "abcd" 
> key = "12" 
> step = 2 
> result = "1ab2cd"
> ```

First  ->Think about variables. How many and which kind of variable are your need.

```
    int step,word;
    string text,key,result;
```

Second ->Fill variables with needed values

```
    Console.Write("Enter Text : ")
    text = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.Write("Enter Key : ")
    key = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.Write("Enter Step : ")
    step = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
```

Third  ->Create an algorthym for solve this problem

Forth  ->Think about what exception can be and how can you solve them

```
    for(int i=0;i<key.Length;i++)
    {
        result+=key.Substring(i,1);
        for(int k=0; k<step; k++)
        {
           try
           {
               result+=text.Substring(word,1);
               word++;
           }
           catch
           {
               /* This blok will break 
                  when the text variable's last part's character count lest then step. */
               break;
           }
        }
     }
        if(word < text.Length)
        {
             // if there is any text after all. Calculate how many letter left then write them
             result += text.Substring(word,(text.Length-word))
        }

Console.Write("Result Text : "+result);
Console.ReadKey();
```

I hope this can help to you

Comment: How to implement this algorithm in the opposite direction?

**For example:**
Decipher "1ab2cd" to variables: text = "abcd" and key = "12" (key.Length and step variables are known).

Comment: if you want give a result like ab1cd2 or a12bcd. you have to change something if you want ab1cd2 you have to change step's place its little bit complicated and hour is 5a.m if you want i can write it tomorrow and for 2nd choice you can do it simply with switch key and text variables places on for loop. where are you see key put there text and where are you see text put key there too :D

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry I can't test this.  I hope it helps:

```
     static string Combine(string text, string key, int step)
     {
        var result = "";
        int stepCount = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < text.Length + key.Length; i++)
        {
            if (i % step == 0)
            {
                result += key[i / step];
                stepCount++;
            }
            else
            {
                result += text[i - stepCount];
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```